# symfony doctrine:build --all

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have started to learn symfony and I am a little bit confused. In 'practical symfony' they explain `symfony doctrine:build --model`, `symfony doctrine:build --sql` and `symfony doctrine:insert-sql` but then they mention `symfony doctrine:build -all` without explaining what tasks are included in this command.

Could anybody advice me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`build --all` includes

```
--model             Build model classes
--forms            Build form classes
--filters          Build filter classes
--sql              Build SQL
--db               Drop, create, and either insert SQL or migrate the database
```

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate all your base classes using:

```
php symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
```

It regenerates model classes, forms and filters ones without changing your DB.

On an existing projet, if you have to update your schema and your DB, you should discover Doctrine migrations usage.

Here is some slides about it: http://www.slideshare.net/denderello/symfony-live-2010-using-doctrine-migrations