# Fatal error: Class 'UserForm' not found in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/generator/sfModelGenerator.class.php on 331

Tags: module, symfony1

I have run

```
symfony doctrine:build-model
symfony doctrine:build-form
symfony doctrine:build-module frontend user User
```

But I got

> Fatal error:  Class 'UserForm' not found in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/generator/sfModelGenerator.class.php on 331

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the same problem as explained in this question [symfony doctrine:build --all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225832/symfony-doctrinebuild-all)

Have you tried to regenerate all classes using this?

```
php symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
```